# How can I download all Google App Engine Data?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've been following these instructions to download all my datastore entities into one file.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata#Python_Downloading_and_uploading_all_data

```
appcfg.py download_data --url=http://your_app_id.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api --filename=<data-filename>
```

My remote API is setup and when I run the command and it stops with this feedback in the console.

```
.............[INFO    ] Kind1: No descending index on __key__, performing serial download
[INFO    ] Kind2: No descending index on __key__, performing serial download
[INFO    ] Kind3: No descending index on __key__, performing serial download
..........[INFO    ] [WorkerThread-1] Backing off due to errors: 1.0 seconds
[INFO    ] Resetting backoff to 0.0
```

I'm aware that some reference properties are broken but if there's something else go on that will help.

Comment: This looks like a bug in App Engine, you should log a Defect at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list?can=2&q=Type%3DDefect